# Which Apple TV generations support the use of AirPods?

Tags: appletv, airpods

Does anyone know from experience whether AirPods work with the Apple TV 3rd generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have both 3rd and 4th gen. AirPods only work with 4th unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I do not have personal experience with this, but I did some research.

According to various reports from [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/airpods-and-apple-tv.1992367/) on iMore, AirPods currently work fine with the Apple TV fourth generation (though they need to be paired with it like a standard Bluetooth device) but [many](http://forums.macrumors.com/goto/post?id=24108320#post-24108320) [people](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/airpods-and-apple-tv.1992367/page-2#post-24131779) [have](http://www.imore.com/how-pair-your-airpods-apple-tv-android-and-other-bluetooth-devices#comment-772585) reported that it does not work with the second- or third-generation Apple TV. A [question and answer](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MMEF2AM/A/will-airpod-work-with-appletv-3rd-gen-and-4th-gen/Q29KC4TTKKAX4CUKP) on the Apple store website also agree that it only works with the Apple TV 4 (and, presumably, versions to come).