# How do I switch using my AirPods between my Mac and my iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

I have AirPods that I often need to switch using between my Mac and my iPhone. I never do this during a conversation, but often I'll have used them on my phone for a phone call, and then need to use them on my Mac; or vice versa. Doing this involves multiple steps on both ends (whatever is required for an explicit BT connect) and even then, doesn't seem to "stick" until the APs disconnect and reconnect to the switched-to end several times (often interrupting whatever I've started doing there).

How is this supposed to work?

---

Note that I'm aware of [the claims](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253712/4395) that this should be a seamless process. But it doesn't work that way for me, or any of the dozen or so other people I know in similar situations.

Comment: @JBallin No. Seen the link and the comment.

Comment: What’s your idea of seamless? They work pretty darn well. They should auto add to your bt devices and you just try connecting to it and it switches. They don’t support being connecting to multiple devices simultaneously like the bose QC35 if that’s what you’re getting at.

Comment: Can you clarify your issues with switching devices? There’s a slight delay.

Comment: @JBallin Answer with what you think the steps are.

Comment: I saw the comment. Just because you don’t agree with the answers doesn’t warrant asking a new question.

Comment: Did you read all the answers to the other question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294566/151404

Comment: The way to avoid this being closed as a duplicate is to detail what “it doesn’t work” means. Perhaps lead with the postscript and then build why the linked answers (all of them) don’t work or explain how your situation is somehow materially different than the linked question.

Comment: @JBallin It's not that I don't agree with the answers. But you've got this one closed; I'll ask another that's clearer to avoid confusion. (What it boils down to is this: for me and for everyone I know, AirPods act exactly like any other BT device, in the scenarios asked about — switching from a phone to a Mac; which nothing "seamless" or special about being associated with an Apple ID.)

Comment: I think an interesting question that you're getting at, is what exactly Apple means by "Seamless switching". My personal understanding is that I can "grab control" of the AirPods without disconnecting them from my other device first. I don't think other bluetooth headphones have this functionality? If this isn't working for you, it may be worth trying to reset your AirPods as they can be a little buggy. Hold the button on back and make sure all your devices "forget" them in BT settings, then re-pair.

Comment: @orome I just tested my theory on two different bluetooth devices (QC35's and JBL Speaker) and I was correct. Once they were paired to their max # of devices, I was unable to pair another device without unpairing the last. It tried connecting for ~10 seconds and then said "Connection Unsuccessful", I tried it multiple times with iPhone/iPad/MacBook Pro. This DOES work with AirPods.