# AirPods struggle to switch between iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, airpods

Typically my AirPods are connected to my iPhone, but often I want to switch them to my Mac and vice-versa.

When I <kbd>Option</kbd> click the audio menulet, I can select my AirPods and I even see their current battery life. However, when I select them, they do not connect.

Similarly, when they're connected to my Mac, I can't select them on my iPhone.  They are paired with both devices.

The only thing that fixes this is a reboot of my Mac or iPhone (whichever I am trying to connect to).

This is cumbersome though. Is there at least a service or something I can kill that will reset my bluetooth on macOS? Any other suggestions to resolve this issue?

I am using an iPhone X running iOS 12 and my Mac is running macOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: Take a look at the [answers to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253711/88313) and see if any of them help.

Comment: I think that question and the answers within it describe seamless switching vs manual switching. But in my case, I'm saying manual switching doesn't work until I restart the target machine.

I'll my question with a video soon for better context.