# Is there a way to make AirPods connect to AppleTV without having to go deep into AppleTV's menus?

Tags: appletv, airpods

My AirPods have been paired to my AppleTV long time ago.  But typically, I use them with my iPhone or iPad.

Every once in a while, usually at night, I want to watch a show on AppleTV using my AirPods.  However, the process of having to go deep into AppleTV's menus just to get the AirPods connected is a cumbersome process.

I asked Siri for help, but she had no idea what I was talking about when I used the Siri Remote to say "Hey Siri, connect to my AirPods".  And I did this when the AirPods are in my ear and have already played me the "I am ON" DING sound.

So, the question becomes:

Can I use any automated way to get the AirPods to connect to my AppleTV as "lazily" as possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually (sometimes I do have to go deep into the menu’s) you should be able to swipe down from the top, using your Apple TV remote (works in most apps - not all), and then select your audio device by selecting the “Audio” tab, going down to “Speaker”, and selecting your Bluetooth device.

Alternatively, you can hold the “play/pause” button on your remote when in the “TV” or “Menu” views and select the audio output in a pop up menu.

Related [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/294566/151404) (my own) about how to use AirPods easily with multiple devices.

Comment: The question is about connecting the AirPods to the AppleTV.  I don’t want to use my iPhone.

Comment: How is my answer related to an iPhone?

Comment: My bad. Missed the remote part.

Comment: @HanSooloo did this solve your problem?